# How to make atomic controller actions in Sails.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

Let's say I want to do a bunch of operations in a Sails.js controller. Not just database operations, but also some plain Javascript processing. For instance, something like fetching several rows, do some data analysis, and then make a save a new row in another table. (This is just an example, don't limit your answer to just this one. You can think of other examples yourself)

How can I make sure the operation is atomic so that the result is correct?

As far as I know, Sails.js doesn't support transactions.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MySQL, there is an adapter called [sails-mysql-transactions](https://github.com/postmanlabs/sails-mysql-transactions) that supports transactions. You would use this instead of the sails-mysql adapter.